# не удается конвертировать.py в .exe

Tags: python, cx-freeze

В setup.py такой код `

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python/tcl/tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python/tcl/tk8.6'

buildOptions = dict (
    packages = ['os','tkinter','matplotlib.pyplot','numpy'],
    excludes = [],
    include_files = ['c:/python/DLLs/tcl86t.dll', 'c:/python/DLLs/tk86t.dll']
    )
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None    


executables = [
    Executable('plot.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='editor',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

`
Использую такие библиотеки 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import os

from tkinter import *
Получаю такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вместо matplotlib.pyplot попробуй написать просто matplotlib

Comment: @Raccoon, не стоит создавать дубли своих же вопросов, они так же будут закрываться. В предыдущем вопросе уже есть ссылка на вопрос с ответом, который вам может помочь. Если он вам не помог, лучше задавать уже конкретный вопрос, с указанием что вы сделали, и что у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать модуль [py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907258/how-do-i-compile-my-python-3-app-to-). Выглядит он многообещающим (или ещё один [сайтик](https://dsy.name/note/py2exe)).

Для третьего Python'а можно скачать [тут](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe).